# Get data from database of Wordpress in Plugin

Tags: database, wordpress

I am trying to get last inserted data from WP database but it shows nothing.

**code :**

```
global $wpdb;
    $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
    $table = $wpdb->prefix."videos";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = '$lastid'");
     foreach ( $result as $print )   {

  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $print->video.'</td>';

  echo '</tr>';
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

From [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row) (emphasis mine):

> **After insert**, the ID generated for the AUTO_INCREMENT column can be
>   accessed with:
>
> $wpdb->insert_id

It only makes sense to use `$wpdb->insert_id` after an insert statement.  Otherwise it won't be set.

Depending on your table and your requirements, something like:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = (select max(id) from $table)");
```

might do what you need.